# Route Map Direction on Bing Maps in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

How to show the Route path from one place to another place using bingmaps in WP7?
i am having user starting latitude,longitude and destination latitude,longitude values...
Please tell me....any samples please let me know...

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Couldn't you just use a BingMapsDirectionTask instead?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your needs and if you wish to customise your "Map".

There are two options available:

1. [Use Bing Maps Direction Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394024%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) - (very good, quick tutorial)
2. [Use the Bing Maps control in your app](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/mobile.aspx) - (you will need to sign up for a developer account, then follow the tutorials on how to call the various services to get route information based on start and end points and then finally show them on the map)

number 2 is more challenging, however will offer much greater levels of customisation

Comment: How to Pass start latitude,longitude and destination latitude and longitude as parameters in BingMapDirection Task....

Comment: you set the "Start" and "End" properties on the [BingMapsDirectionTaskClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapsdirectionstask(v=vs.92).aspx)